# How to get the answer to $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-5}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

It looks fairly simple:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-5}}$$

The answer is $$\sqrt{2x-5}$$

How is this done?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Consider giving [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to past, present and future respondents. You will also be able to up vote at 15 rep.

Comment: Thanks, probablyme.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the substitution $$u = 2x-5$$. Then $$du = 2 dx $$.

So after the change of variables, we have $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt {u}} du$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: If you find this answer satisfactory, feel free to accept it. Happy to help!